# How to control play section of MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm making app using MPMoviePlayerController.

I want to make special function.

What I want to function is like this.

If I play movie, player will stop after few second (ex: 30sec).

If I click play button, player has to play from 30sec to next stop point.

For me to realize this function, I've used  `initialPlaybackTime` and `endPlaybackTime` option of `MPMoviePlayerContrller`.

But, this function didn't work like my thought.

> mplayer.initialPlaybackTime = 0;
> mplayer.endPlaybackTime = 10;
>
> [mplayer play];
>
> ....
> [mplayer pause];
>
> ,,,
>
> mplayer.initialPlaybackTime = 10;
> mplayer.endPlaybackTime =30;
> [mplayer play];

And, mplayer is played again from 0 to 10, not from 10 to 30.

Answer (score 10):

This is a little late, but for anyone who comes upon this question, it appears that endplaybacktime and initialplayback time can only be set once for an initialized mpmovieplayercontroller. If you want to reset the values you'll have to destroy your mpmovieplayercontroller instance and create a new one.

This is very disappointing, could I be wrong? I would love it if I were.

Comment: This is ridiculous. I'm submitting a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to set the `currentPlaybackTime` before restarting the playback. Note, the order of initializing these properties does matter.

```
[...]
mplayer.initialPlaybackTime = 10.0;
mplayer.endPlaybackTime = 30.0;
mplayer.currentPlaybackTime = 10.0;
[mplayer play];
```